# Sending zip file as attchment in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have zipped several files in my ruby script. Before attachment total sizes of all files is almost 12 MB and after zipping size of the result file is almost 8.3 MB which is attachment.zip. I am sending this file using actionmailer as attachment as follows:

```
attachments[file_name] = File.read(path_of_the_file)
receivers = ["a@b.com", "b@c.com"]
mail(:to => receivers, :subject => subject, :body => "").deliver
```

But the problem is that it keeps giving error **554 Message rejected: Stream is more than 10485760 bytes long.**  It is giving the same error while I was sending the files individually before zipping. I have no idea how to fix this. So I will be really grateful if anyone helps to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The message is being rejected by the server your app is connecting to.

Either make your message smaller than 10485760 bytes, or use a different server to send your mail which doesn't have that restriction.

Comment: Is it because of the line File.read? I am asking because when the size of the zip file is 8.3 MB why is it giving the error that size is greater than something around 10 MB.

Comment: From the error, the entire stream is greater than 10MB, not just your email. This is all of the data sent to the mail server in the process of sending your mail. Are you sure you're not sending anything else?

Comment: Yes Jon, I have written above exactly what we have sent. So I don't understand even after zipping this why the stream size is same as that before when the file was not zipped

Comment: Can you try it again with just a single receiver? Might be that the mail server is doing something weird and duplicating your message size that way ...

Comment: Amazon SES has this limitation.  If you're using a service which uses SES as the sender, you'll get this error on attachments > 10mb too.